# Okular version 1 Auto Save Annotations

Tags: okular, kde5, kde-apps

I recently moved my OS from Ubuntu 14 to 18. Unfortunately, unlike in my previous setup it seems current Okular version 1.3.3 does not allow auto save of annotations. Is there a way to set auto-save back in? Seems the current workaround in using Save as.